# Should I store data pre-ordered rather than ordering on the fly?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL and I'm wondering if it's a good strategy to presort my data so when a user accessed the information, it's not having to sort it on the fly?

Basically, I have an HTML table with is being populated with paginated data from the database, this is ordered by a particular column and can sometimes be a little sluggish - I was thinking about reordering the table on a nightly basis so the `order by` can be removed from the query.

Is this general practice or should I avoid this?

**Update**

My query is as follows:

```
'select keyword, position, impressions, clicks, ctr 
 from keywords where profile_id=%s
 order by impressions desc limit %s, %s', (profile_id, start, end))
```

My table looks like this:

```
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| profile_id          | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| landing_page_id     | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| keyword             | varchar(2083) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position            | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| impressions         | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ctr                 | float         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| clicks              | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| unique_key          | varchar(200)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| position_30_days    | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| impressions_30_days | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| clicks_30_days      | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ctr_30_days         | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position_60_days    | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| impressions_60_days | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| clicks_60_days      | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ctr_60_days         | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position_90_days    | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| impressions_90_days | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| clicks_90_days      | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ctr_90_days         | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on that column? That's usually enough. Also, is it unique? Could that column be used as a primary key?

Comment: Yea, I've got one on there for it. No it's no unique - It's a metrics column.

Comment: Does removing the order by significantly speed up the query?

Comment: Good question, I'll try it...

Comment: Yes, it's a lot faster without the `order by`

Comment: I think you you're using `ORDER BY field LIMIT x, y`, and this is a major source of slowness. Could please post the query and the table structure: `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`

Comment: You cannot pre-order the data; a table is "unordered".  But... Some of the comments do not agree with each other; please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the statement with the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @RickJames a table in MySQL is ordered by its primary key if no other order is imposed on it. That is how it's stored on disk. But I do agree with you that it's not a _guaranteed_ order.

Comment: Thanks for comments so far. I've updated the question with the information requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the data in an ordered way maybe useful in some rare cases, but it doesn't guarantee that the selected rows will be ordered. You will have to use `order by` to guarantee the order of the returned rows.

Is it general practice? I don't think so.

Should I avoid this? Yes, at least for this specific case

**Alternative solution:**

To let this query run faster, and reduce the sorting process, add a composite index on profileid ASC and on impressions DESC:

```
ALTER TABLE keywords ADD INDEX (profile_id ASC, impressions DESC).
```

**IMPORTANT:** drop the other index on `profile_id` (The name of the index you should drop will be displayed if you run "`SHOW CREATE TABLE keywords`")

**Other factors that could affect the performance:**

- The cardinality, or data distribution. For example, some profiles may have much more entries than others. A useful way to check that is:

  ```
  `SELECT profile_id, count(*) cc FROM keywords GROUP BY profile_id ORDER BY cc ASC limit 10;`
  `SELECT profile_id, count(*) cc FROM keywords GROUP BY profile_id ORDER BY cc DESC limit 10;`
  ```

  If the numbers are hugely different, the same query may vary in performance based on the number of rows a profile has.
- If a profile has huge number of rows, using limit x, y will gradually worsen when x (the offset) get's higher.

Comment: Thanks, that's helped a lot, can I add the composite indexes across, the other impression columns (30, 60 and 90 days)?

Comment: Yes, you can add more than one composite index. If you have the same query as above, with `impressions_30_days` instead of `impressions`, a composite index on `profileid` and `impressions_30_days` would be useful, and so on.

Comment: Won't work as stated.  `INDEX(a ASC, b DESC)` is _syntactically_ accepted, but the `ASC` and `DESC` are ignored.  Until version 8.0, that is.

Comment: That pair of `SELECTs` needs `GROUP BY profile_id`.

Comment: Right. I missed `GROUP BY` part. Added it.

Answer (score 4):

(`DESCRIBE` is not as descriptive as `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we can't see what indexes you have.)

That one `SELECT` would benefit from this 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(profile_id, impressions) -- in that order.
```

Do you have a keyword that is 2083 characters long?  If not, why have such a big `VARCHAR`?

Why have both `unique_key` and `id`?  Is `unique_key` some form of UUID?  They are notoriously inefficient when the table gets huge.

`LIMIT ?, ? ... ($start, $end)` -- The two numbers in `LIMIT` are `start` and `count`, not `end`.

By using the index, above, and changing to "remember where you left off", you can make the `ORDER BY...LIMIT` work a lot faster.  [*Details*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) .  This suggestion, if practical for your application, will be faster (at least after the first 'page') than your original question about ordering the data could ever be!  Why?  Because `OFFSET` (the first number in `LIMIT`) requires work.  My blog show how to get rid of that work.

**More**

When you could have multiple rows with the same value, and you need to be deterministic in ordering:

```
ORDER BY profile_id DESC, impression DESC, id DESC)
INDEX   (profile_id,      impression,      id)
```

Notes:

- In the `ORDER BY`, all the items are in the same direction (`DESC` is usually what is wanted).
- Mixing ASC and DESC prevents use of the index (until 8.0).
- Since you are looking for a single `profile_id`, `ASC` and `DESC` on it have identical effect.

To deal with a 'compound' $leftoff, let's look at the above example.  After assuming that `profile_id` is constant, we want to somehow remember where you left off as a pair of `$impression, $id`, then do

```
WHERE   impression <= $impression
  AND ( impression <  $impression OR id < $id )
```

alternatively (and it is unclear whether these optimize differently in different versions of mysql):

```
WHERE ( impression = $impression AND id < $id
     OR impression < $impression )
```

Comment: Yea, the composite index seems to have sped things up. The keyword being so long is just to cover for long ones, though, I'm sure I can shorten it! The unique key is hash between to `landing_page_id` and the `keyword`, this is to stop duplicate keywords being added into this table.

Comment: Reading your blog, so basically, I make the above query and save the `id` for the next call and just add `... and id >= %s` and this stops the table having to be fully scanned again?

Comment: If keyword were shortened enough, you could simply have `UNIQUE(landing_page_id, keyword)` (in either order).

Comment: `WHERE profile_id = %s AND impressions >= %s ORDER BY profile_id DESC, impressions DESC LIMIT 10` will give you the next 10 rows, _without_ touching any other rows.

Comment: I'm not following now, why is it not `...impressions <= %s...`  if we're displaying the next set of results which would be less then not more than

Comment: Oops, I should have said `<=`.

Comment: I've been implementing your suggestions and upon completion and running tests, i've realised that the impression count can stop changing as I get deeper into the pagination and therefore the data won't change. For example, the last 50 rows might all have an impression count of 20, so the query can't show me the next 10 of those 50 as the impression count doesn't go below. I tried a new composite index as follows `(profile_id asc, impression desc, id desc)` with the hopes to stop the min row id and add that as a condition `..and id <...` however, that isn't working. Do you have a work around?

Comment: @Adders - You must "remember that you left off" at "$impressions, $id".  That is, hang onto both, and use both in the "get next 50 rows".  Also, don't mix `ASC` and `DESC`, else the index cannot be used.  (8.0 excepted).

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the `ORDER BY` from the query. SQL is set-based and as such is unordered. What you *could* do, however, *if you can't optimise your query*, is using MySQL's "poor man's materialized view": a secondary table that is regularly updated from your primary table.

How often your secondary table needs to be updated, depends on how often the data in your primary table changes and how quickly you need that change to be reflected on your web page.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_secondary_table;

CREATE TABLE my_secondary_table
SELECT *
FROM my_primary_table
ORDER BY my_ordering;
```

First you [drop](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html) the secondary table if needed, then you [recreate it by copying](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) your primary table.

Now you need to schedule this to happen once a night or once an hour, depending on your needs.
*Note that the secondary table is inaccessible while it is dropped and created again.*

You can specify your columns and create a primary key for your secondary table that aligns with your ordering. Since MySQL stores the data of a table "behind" its primary key, retrieval in that order should be quite fast.
If you cannot use any (combination) of your columns as the primary key, you can emulate a row numbering in your select and use that as the primary key, as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE my_secondary_table (pk INT, PRIMARY KEY(pk))
SELECT
   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS pk,
   mpt.*
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM my_primary_table
   ORDER BY my_ordering
) mpt
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) rn;
```

Comment: "Inaccessible" -- This can be solved by (1) creating a `new` table, then (2) `RENAME TABLE secondary_table TO old, new TO secondary_table;`