# Inconsistent keyset pagination when using (timestamp, uuid) fields

Tags: postgresql, query, pagination

I am using the keyset pagination method for uuids on my Postgres database described in this post:

- [How to do Pagination with UUID v4 and Created Time on Concurrent Inserted Data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267794/how-to-do-pagination-with-uuid-v4-and-created-time-on-concurrent-inserted-data)

However, I have noticed when I have two records where the date is the same, rows are being skipped from the result.

For example when I run the query:

```
SELECT id, created_at FROM collection
ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC
```

I get the records back as I expect them, with `created_at` being the primary order, then `id` acting as a tiebreaker:

| id | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| e327847a-7058-49cf-bd91-f562412aedd9 | 2022-05-23 23:07:22.592 |
| d35c6bb8-06dd-4b86-b5c6-d123340520e2 | 2022-05-23 23:07:22.592 |
| 5167cf95-953f-4f7b-9881-03ef07adcf3c | 2022-05-23 23:07:22.592 |
| d14f48dc-df22-4e98-871a-a14a91e8e3c1 | 2022-05-23 23:07:21.592 |

However when I run a query to paginate through like:

```
SELECT id, created_at
FROM collection
WHERE (created_at, id) < ('2022-05-23 23:07:22.592','d35c6bb8-06dd-4b86-b5c6-d123340520e2')
ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 3
```

I would expect to get back the last two records, but my result set is instead

| id | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| d14f48dc-df22-4e98-871a-a14a91e8e3c1 | 2022-05-23 23:07:21.592 |

I've also tried some variations on the query to try to fix it, such as:

```
SELECT id, created_at
FROM collection
WHERE created_at < '2022-05-23 23:07:22.592' OR
     (created_at = '2022-05-23 23:07:22.592' AND id < 'd35c6bb8-06dd-4b86-b5c6-d123340520e2')
ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC
```

But I still get back the same result set.

What's going on with my query?

Comment: Time stamps generally go to microseconds, but you show only milliseconds.  I suspect your problem is a mismatch in rounding, leading to values appearing equal when they are not.

Comment: Right. I cannot reproduce your result with the data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Either of your shown queries should return ***two*** rows, as expected:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f9d066ef2a3155dfd9995aaf36896f80)*

If you see a different result, then the likely cause is **index corruption**. Test with:

```
SELECT id, created_at
FROM collection
WHERE (created_at + interval '1 ms', id)
    < ('2022-05-23 23:07:22.592','d35c6bb8-06dd-4b86-b5c6-d123340520e2')
ORDER BY created_at + interval '1 ms' DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

That "disables" index support and gets the result of a sequential scan. See:

- [text column compares equal to where clause but does not select matching row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292185/text-column-compares-equal-to-where-clause-but-does-not-select-matching-row/292200#292200)

If so, fix with:

```
REINDEX TABLE collection;
```

Or just the involved index on `(created_at, id)`.

I have hardly ever seen index corruption myself. Typically, there is a troubling root cause, like failing hardware (RAM, storage) or a very old version of Postgres. Try to find and fix the cause.

This might be a good time for a backup of your database first.

Related:

- [Efficient pagination for big tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219782/efficient-pagination-for-big-tables/219810#219810)